# Reactive pipeline subscribed but in unit test Mockito.verify() fails (no invocation of mocks is recorded)

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have this class:

```java
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class SyncTransactionService {
    private final SyncProducerService syncProducerService; // kafka producer
    private final CouponService couponService; // db persistence service
    private final CouponUpdateMessageMapper mapper; // simple mapper to generate message dto for Kafka

    public void processChanges(List<Change> changes) {
        Flux.fromIterable(changes)
                    .map(this::processAndSend)
                    .doOnError(e -> log.error("Cannot sync coupon with change. ", e))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
                    .subscribe();
    }

    private Mono<CouponUpdateMessage> processAndSend(Change change) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> change)
                .doFirst(() -> log.info("saving or deleting the coupon: {}", change.getChanged()))
                .map(this::saveOrDelete)
                .thenReturn(mapper.map(change))
                .doOnSuccess(message -> log.info("sending message: {}", message))
                .doOnSuccess(syncProducerService::send);
    }

    private Mono<Void> saveOrDelete(Change change) {
        if (change.getType() == DELETE) return couponService.deleteCoupon(change.getChanged());
        else return couponService.saveCoupon(change.getChanged()).then();
    }

}
```

And this test:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SyncTransactionServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private SyncProducerService syncProducerService;

    @Mock
    private CouponService couponService;

    @Mock
    private CouponUpdateMessageMapper mapper;

    @InjectMocks
    private SyncTransactionService syncTransactionService;


    private static Coupon insertId1;
    private static Coupon updateId2;
    private static Coupon deleteId3;

    private static Change change1;
    private static Change change2;
    private static Change change3;


    @BeforeAll
    private static void prepareData() {
        insertId1 = DataHelper.coupon();
        updateId2 = DataHelper.coupon();
        updateId2.setId(2);
        deleteId3 = DataHelper.coupon();
        deleteId3.setId(3);

        change1 = Change.builder().changed(insertId1).type(CouponUpdateType.INSERT).build();
        change2 = Change.builder().changed(updateId2).type(CouponUpdateType.UPDATE).build();
        change3 = Change.builder().changed(deleteId3).type(CouponUpdateType.DELETE).build();
    }

    @Test
    void shouldProcessChanges() {
        // given
        List<Change> changes = List.of(change1, change2, change3);
        when(couponService.saveCoupon(insertId1)).thenReturn(Mono.just(insertId1));
        when(couponService.saveCoupon(updateId2)).thenReturn(Mono.just(updateId2));
        when(couponService.deleteCoupon(deleteId3)).thenReturn(Mono.empty());
        doNothing().when(syncProducerService).send(any());
        doCallRealMethod().when(mapper).map(any());

        // when
        syncTransactionService.processChanges(changes);

        // then
        verify(couponService, times(2)).saveCoupon(any());
        verify(mapper, times(3)).map(any());
        verify(couponService).deleteCoupon(any());
        verify(syncProducerService, times(3)).send(any());
    }
}
```

When I run the test, `Mockito.verify()` does not detect any interaction with the mocks, although I have `subscribe()` in the code.

So what could be the problem in my pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your method under test runs asynchronously because of the specified scheduler. You should return the Flux from your method under test and then use `StepVerifier` or call `collectList()` and `block()` methods on the Flux to trigger and wait execution.

Comment: Yes you are right. It seems that I cannot `subscribe()` in the middle of my method to test to get the result; if it is to be tested, I should return the pipeline and do what you said. I will post details below. Thanks!

Comment: So, `Schedulers.elastic()` is recommended? Or I just let it subscribe() without using any `Schedulers` so I can subscribe?

Comment: it depends on what is your processing do;
you should use elastic scheduler if it does some blocking IO operations

Comment: Yes then I think here I have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as @Martin Tarjányi said, if a method of reactive is to be tested and it is with `Schedulers.elastic()`, it will launch async jobs which you cannot immediately finish and thus I see no interactions.

If I stick to it, I can:

- wait until it finishes;(use `https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility` lib or just `Thread.sleep()`, like: `Awaitility.waitAtMost(Duration.ofMillis(2000)).untilAsserted(() -> {verify(...);});`)
- or, return the pipeline and test it with `StepVerifier` or `block()`. **Remember, for a flux, use `blockLast()` to get all; `blockFirst()` only emits the first element.**

So it is like this now:

```java
...
    public Flux<CouponUpdateMessage> processChanges(List<Change> changes) {
        return Flux.fromIterable(changes)
                .flatMap(this::processAndSend)
                .doOnError(e -> log.error("Cannot sync coupon with change. ", e))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()); // don't subscribe() here, but return it
    }
...
```

And test:

```java
...
   // when
   syncTransactionService.processChanges(changes).blockLast(); // process all elements

...
```

And I see the logs and all the interactions are recorded as I wish.

---

If I am not obliged to use `Schedulers.elastic()`, I can just simply `subscribe()`, and the test in the question will work.